# pass data from head to body in html to bootstrap an angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrapping

I am working on an app which part of it is based on mvc razor and vanilla javascript and some part of it is an angular app. I need to pass some json data generated from an script in head of the page to the body part which is an angular app. The format is something like this:

**CODE:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/build/bundles/sharedStyles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/build/bundles/staticStyles.css" />
        <script>
            *** (In this script I am calling an api asyncly to get some config and bootstrap the angular app with this config)
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <test-app></test-app>
        <script src="/js/build/bundles/allScripts.js" type="text/javascript </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code snippet above, I need to pass the result of the api async call to the angular app, what would be the best approach to do so? I know that angular has a concept of app initializer like this:

```
provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: DataFactory, multi: true, deps: [dataService] }
```

but still I am very lost on how pass something from head to body and make angular app wait for that value to be fetched completely in some sort of promise before it starts bootstrapping. Any help or code example would be appreciated

Comment: which angular is that angular 2 or angular 4?

Comment: it is angular 4

Comment: can you get that data in typescript?

Comment: in type script you can access or import json file

Comment: Sounds like you only need a simple callback

Comment: @bresleveloper can you expand on that with an example? not sure how callback will help here

Comment: @Nihal which json file? this will be a json  result from an async api

Comment: that async API must have methods for typescripts

Comment: There is a single line to bootstrap angular and it can be called at your own time for example after a jQuery Ajax. Unfortunately not near a computer for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right path here. `APP_INITIALIZER` is a collection of app initialization functions which can be async as well.

Basically what this means is, it lets you defer the initialization process until a certain task is done (e.g. loading some data).

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => {
        // return a promise here 
      },
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In order to make this work, you need to have access to whatever API you want to call that will defer your process. For example, if, as you've mentioned, you have an async call that will fetch a config object, this async call needs to be done from within the factory function, which will in turn return a promise.

For example:

```
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          SOME_GLOBAL_WITH_ASYNC_API.fetchConfig(resolve, reject);
        });
      },
      multi: true
    }
```

Where `SOME_GLOBAL_WITH_ASYNC_API.fetchConfig` is your async function you want to call to fetch your config.

Something along those lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The reason I moved the api call to head was that api call will take some time hence loading the page slower, I wanted to move the api call to an earlier step like in head to save up some time but unfortunately I don't know how to access and wait for the result in the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a good idea to quickly read through the Angular architecture overview documentation https://angular.io/guide/architecture, it gives you a great holistic explanation of how it is all meant to function.

Specifcally look at services, https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4, services are responsible for feeding data to a component, the component will be calling an observable. All explained in that tutorial link.

From here you can simply data bind the data from the component into the html template.

Comment: My question is not about inside of angular app and how to bind data within html and component. This is happening on an higher level when angular app has not started yet.